# Script mypy raise error in imported package

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

importing ruamel.yaml causing mypy error:

```
Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\comments.py:1118: error: Type signature has too few arguments
```

How can I ignore this error, I have tried:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML  # type: ignore
from ruamel.yaml import YAML  # mypy: ignore
```

mypy==0.761

Comment: I have opened a ticket for this: https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml/tickets/336/

Answer (score 0):

At your `mypy.ini` you can specify ignoring by modules:

```
[mypy-tests.*]
ignore_errors = True
```